# How to push an intermediate commit during interactive rebase in git?

Tags: git

I have a local branch set to track the remote origin/master and it was created by

"git checkout -b mybranch origin/master"

Now after that, I have two separate local commits on the same local branch, and commit2 is depends on commit1

Now I want to push the changes include in the commit1 to the remote branch, what's the right way to do that?

I have run "git rebase -i" and change the commit1 to edit, and git stop at commit 1 when rebasing, which is what I want.

But if I try to do something like "git push", I got error message saying

"fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

```
git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

",

Now assume the hash of my commit1 is "abce", what's the right way to push this change to remote origin/master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git status` tells you how can you cancel the rebase in your working copy. (probably `git rebase --abort`)

And then you can push specific commits like this:

```
git push <remotename> <commit SHA>:<remotebranchname>
```

Answer (score 2):

Although Lajos's answer is correct, you can do it even easeier - error msg gave you everything :)

```
pick xxxxxx 
exec git push <remotename> HEAD:<remotebranchname>
pick xxxxxy
exec git push <remotename> HEAD:<remotebranchname>
pick xxxxxz
```

This way you are always pushing HEAD so you don't have to copy/paste SHA arround.

Comment: Do be careful to make sure you use the correct branch name if you're not wanting to push to master.

Comment: True, edited to make it more generic.